# Not loading image from local path in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

It's not loading any image from local path, but loading images from internet. Please help me load images from local.
I have created the folder containing images inside the project itself.

> **test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-app',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    image1= '/img1.png';
    image2= 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCNTJ-wSPyf8KvKYO-SKhfWi6EkpfgpaBYpcmWlpcyiHhXhzCvBw';
    constructor(){ }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

> **test.component.html**

```
<img class="mx-auto d-block" [src]="image1" alt="Image 1">
<img class="mx-auto d-block" [src]="image2" alt="Image 2">
```

**Error coming on the page**

```
Cannot GET /img1.png
```

Comment: Add your images in the assets folder enter the path as "assets/imagePath". Example - <img src="assets/images/img1.png" />. Check for spelling, extension of file name.

Comment: Welcome :-)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ***Images*** folder in **assets** folder and give the path.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem and being new, and this is my first response, so hopefully, I am not breaking any rules here.

My suggestions for image issues

1. ensure all paths and links case MATCHED ie "image" folder is different than "Image"
2. Important to match "assets" small 'A' both in "angular.json" and in "component.html"
3. add a / before assets

Hopefully this helps someone!

good luck